# Determining discharge curve of capacitor with I(V) curve

Tags: capacitor, current, discharge

I have a **1 F** double layer capacitor in a circuit supplying power to a micro-controller and an RTC circuit.  I will be measuring the **I(V)** from 5 V to 0 V  Is there a way to predict the discharge curve, **V(t)**, from the I(V) curve?

By I(V) curve I mean measuring the current load at voltages from 5 Volts to 0 Volts in 1 milliVolt divisions.  If I can do this in LTspice I am up for that.

I would like to do this with an arbitrary initial charge so I can do some what-if scenarios.

Comment: Spice can use "analog behavioral functions". LTspice would do ... https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use numerical methods to solve this. The derivative can be approximated by a delta. Here it is in Excel. You will need to substitute your I(V) data. You can use a lookup function for that.

For my example, the time interval is coarse, you will want to use a finer increment.

[image]

With "show formulas" enabled:
[image]

Comment: I was giving this a try but excel spent a lot of time doing the lookup for the calculations.  I may try pushing it into VBA, a c or python program to crunch the data then import to excel for the graphing.